# ImportError: No module named gobject

Tags: python, linux, ros

I installed ros1 and created a catkin workspace. Inside the src folder I cloned a ros package "executive_smach_visualization". But when I try to run it with the following command I am getting an error.

```
rosrun smach_viewer smach_viewer.py
```

Traceback:

```
wxversion 2.8 is not installed, installed versions are ['3.0-gtk3']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/developer/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/scripts/smach_viewer.py", line 77, in <module>
from smach_viewer import xdot
File "/home/developer/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/src/smach_viewer/xdot/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import wxxdot
File "/home/developer/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/src/smach_viewer/xdot/wxxdot.py", line 22, in <module>
from xdot import *
File "/home/developer/catkin_ws/src/executive_smach_visualization/smach_viewer/src/smach_viewer/xdot/xdot.py", line 34, in <module>
import gobject
ImportError: No module named gobject
```

I have already tried following:

1) Installed goobject using pip

2) cloned gobject from git to src folder of catkin_ws, catkin_make and setup.bash

What could be the problem? Please let me know if I am missing any important input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you more than 1 version of python?

Comment: What is your `pip --version` output?

Comment: @vishal yes I do have Python 2.7.15rc1 and Python 3.6.7.

Comment: @Benyamin Jafari command "python -V" gives python 2.7.15rc1 and command "python3 -V" gives python 3.6.7

Comment: @Skanda I want to see `pip` version, not Python version.

Comment: pip 19.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs if there is different version of ros, python and so on.

It seems package is a little bit outdated.

**Edit:**

After downloading package and when building your working environment, use:

```
catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

[Please refer to 1.5 section (User configuration) of this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Arch#User_configuration)

Comment: Is there any way I can get over with this error? I need python 3.6 for ubuntu and python 2.7 for ros.(I have only one version of ros)

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.